# TimeSeries not showing any value if it contain only one value

Tags: java, jsp, jfreechart

```
TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Year Chart",Month.class);
series.add(cal.getTime,500);
TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection(series);
```

i.e series contain only one value it can't show anything on graph.

```
TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Year Chart",Month.class);
series.add(cal.getTime,100);
series.add(cal.getTime,500);
TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection(series);
```

i.e When it contain more than one value it shows on graph

What to do if i want to shows value even series contain only one value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add just one item, it's probably there. You just have to make the series shapes visible in your renderer to see anything. Try something like this.

```
renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
```